# No trust in His servants, and charging His malachim?

Tags: commentaries, job-iyov-book-of

Iyov 4:18 Behold, In His (HaShem's) servants '*lo yamin*', and in His messengers '*yasim toholah*'.

Behold, He putteth no trust in His servants, and His angels He chargeth with folly (or error).

I Have two questions regarding this verse:
First:
Is this verse referring to man and heavenly or dive beings (angels),
or is it referring to just human beings? Because can't find any reference to angels in the rest of the context (verses 17-21) and the context opens with mortal man, human beings.

Second:
If this verse refers to 'angels' then why is it HaShem charge them with folly or error? In what way do angels error?

Comment: Maimonides (the Rambam) wrote in his Guide for the Perplexed(in Part II Chapter 6) that angels  have no free will. How can they be charged with folly or error